# htaccess conditional with else RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello i want to set a RewriteRule checking a url parameter as http://example.com/admin/bla/foo, example:

```
If my url contains 'admin' then use:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
else
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ ?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?admin$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ ?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin(?:/|$) index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ ?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This assumes there is no .htaccess in `admin/` directory.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you for your help